# How to get part of a string when concatenating?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, concatenation

To improve the loading speed of my sheet page, I would to try to convert the function below into a script. In fact with the Chrome DevTools, I have tried to delete the column with this function inside and the page speed has increased significantly from 35 sec to 14 sec.

**The function:**

`={"ID"; arrayformula(IF(C2:C="";;(LEFT(C2:C;1))&"-"&(LEFT(D2:D;1))&(LEFT(E2:E;1))&"-"&(UPPER(RIGHT(B2:B;8)))))}`

I don't know how to concatenate only the first character of the col C, the first character of the col D, first character of the col E and the last eight characters of col B. How to run the script only if there is an entry or an update of the values in the columns C,D,E,B?

**The code I tried to write:**

```
function concatenate() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
      var lr = sheet.getLastRow()
      var values1 = sheet.getSheetValues(2, 4, lr, 1);
      var values2 = sheet.getSheetValues(2, 5, lr, 1);
      var values3 = sheet.getSheetValues(2, 2, lr, 1);
      var results = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < lr; i++) {
        results.push([values1[i] + " " + values2[i] + " " + values3[i]]);
      }
      sheet.getRange(2, 1, results.length).setValues(results);
    }
```

Comment: I have update the question. I don't know how to concatenate only the first character of the col C, the first character of the col D, the first character of the col E and the last eight characters of col B.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by **something not works.**?

Comment: The script give me this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined (row 5, file "Code")

Comment: You need to take a basic js course first. Take it online. It'll take less than 5 hours. I edited my answer to show the line you need to replace. But that's all I can do.

Comment: I have tried with another update, but not works anyway. P.S. I'll promise after this question, I'll do it.

Comment: Replace the line in the first code: *The code I tried to write*.

Comment: Now works. Thanks! Only last question. How to run the script only if there is an entry or an update of the values in the columns C,D,E,B?

Comment: Kindly ask a new question preferably after researching triggers in the official documentation. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: I have already start a trigger (temporal or onedit) but the script create a new row after it is launched, I prefer only that the script is launched after a new entry.

Comment: Hi! Ask a new question. See [ask]. SO has a 1-question-1-Answer format. This is not a forum.

Comment: Ok. I will ask a new question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`String.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) to get part of the string:

```
results.push([values1[i][0].slice(0,1) + " " + values2[i][0].slice(0,1) + " " + values3[i][0].slice(-8)]);
```

Note that `values1` is a 2D array. So, `[0]` is needed to index into the inner dimension

Comment: @Mitchell Why don't you read the documentation link and try it? If run into errors, update your question with the error you're running into.